# Asignar valores Map a variables

Tags: java, programación-funcional

Tengo definida la siguiente funcione que llama a un servicio SOAP para lanzar un proceso.

El key del Map que tengo definido corresponde a la variable **company** que hay en el return y el value corresponde a la variable **codProvision**.
Lo que quiero hacer es pasar los valores que tengo almacenados en el Map al return de la función. Osea se que con cada valor realice una llamada defirente, ya que los valores son necesarios para realizar la llamada al servicio.

```
 public Stream<Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {

            boolean manual = false;
            String indManual = Boolean.toString(manual);
            String fechaCalculo = DateUtils.fechaUltimoDiaMesActual();
                    String company ="CGV";
                    String codProvision ="GI02R";

            Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String,String>();

            parametros.put("CGV", "GI02R");
            parametros.put("CMV", "MI05R");
            parametros.put("UCV", "UI02R");

            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(company,indManual, fechaCalculo,codProvision, OUTPUT_QUERY));
}
```

Comment: y si no está el valor que se debe hacer?

Comment: Simpre va a tener valor,nunca esta vacío. @RuslanLópez

Comment: En ese caso `codProvision` no ha sido declarado, asegúrate de subir siempre un [mcve]